# Read from textbox into array php

Tags: php, html, list, post

file index.php

```
<html>  
<head>
    <title>Guset Book</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Guest book</h3>
    <a href="/addNew.php">
        <p><input type="button" value="Add in book" ></p>
    </a>
    <a href="/readAll.php">
        <p><input type="button" value="Read all"></p>
    </a>
</body>
```

file addNew.php

```
<html>  
<head>
    <title>Guset Book</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>New</h3>

    <form name='formAddNew' method='post' action="ControllerAdd.php">
        <p>Author: <input type="text" name="nameAuthor"></p>
        <p>Comment:</p>
        <p><textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="commentAuthor" style="resize: none;"></textarea></p>  
        <p><input type="submit" name="submitAuthor" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

file Model.php

```
<?php
class GuestBook
{
    private $author;
    private $comment;

    function __construct($author, $commment)
    {
        $this->author = $author;
        $this->comment = $commment;
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }
}
$guestBookList = new ArrayObject();
$guestBookList[] = new GuestBook("Author", "Comment");

function addInList($author, $comment)
{
    $guestBookList[] = new GuestBook($author, $comment);
}
```

?>

file ControllerAdd.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        require_once "Model.php";
        addInList($_POST["nameAuthor"], $_POST["commentAuthor"]);
    ?>
    <h3>Succes</h3>
    <a href="/"><input type="button" value="On main"></a>
</body>
```

file readAll.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>
    <?php 
        require_once "Model.php"; 

        foreach($guestBookList as $value)
        {
            echo("<br>-----------<br>");
            echo($value->getAuthor());
            echo("<br>");
            echo($value->getComment());
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

The problem is that complier don't throws a mistakes, but don't write the code into array from textboxes. It read in right way the info from textboxes, but don't write into array Plz help.

Comment: here is none of your own code, where we can see your mistakes or suggestions

Comment: Your code doesn't retrieve/store your data into/from external storage like database or text file, saving this kind of data into cookies/session is useless (imho). Every time when you access to the `Model.php` your `$guestBookList` created (as new instance of object with no data) and added one record with 'author and comment'. I suspect you'll see only this record always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest in your particular case you need to change behaviour of your Model, something like this:

> *it's only an example, and must not be used as is*
>
> I guess, this code don't crash OP source

```
<?php
class GuestBook {
    private $source;
    private $book;

    function __construct($filename) {
        $this->book = array();
        $this->source = $filename;
        $this->restore();
    }

    function getBook() {
        return $this->book;
    }

    function restore() {
        if (file_exists($this->source)) {
            $records = file($this->source);
            if (is_array($records)) {
                while (count($records)) {
                    $line = trim(array_shift($records));
                    list($author, $comment) = explode(':splitter:',$line);
                    $this->book[] = new GuestBookRecord($author, $comment);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function save() {
        $fd = fopen($this->source, 'w');
        foreach ($this->book as $record) {
            fwrite($fd, $record->getAuthor().':splitter:'.$record->getComment().PHP_EOL);
        }
        fclose($fd);
    }

    function addComment($author, $comment) {
        $this->book[] = new GuestBookRecord($author, $comment);
        $this->save();
    }
}

class GuestBookRecord {
    private $author;
    private $comment;

    function __construct($author, $commment) {
        $this->author = $author;
        $this->comment = $commment;
    }

    public function getAuthor() {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getComment() {
        return $this->comment;
    }
}

$guestBook = new GuestBook('sample.txt');

// compatibility with OP source
$guestBookList = $guestBook->getBook();

// compatibility with OP source
function addInList($author, $comment) {
    global $guestBook;
    $guestBook->addComment($author, $comment);
}
```

But it's not so good. Here is minimum 2 problems, first - the code reads all of the records into memory, second - concurrent accessing. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

`Session` are best way to pass variables in this case

if i understand properly then you want to pass text filds value from two page and use them in 3rd page in array.

Use this as reference

```
index.php

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['tex1'])){
        $_SESSION['tex1'] = $_POST['tex1'];
        header('location:form.php');        
    }   
}
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="tex1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

form.php
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['tex2'])){
        $_SESSION['tex2'] = $_POST['tex2'];
        header('location:final_page.php');      
    }

}
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="tex2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

final_page.php

<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

`$_SESSION` is `global variable` of `php`. 
To read more about session. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

file1.php

```
<form action="file2.php" method="POST">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="data[]"> </textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $formData = $_POST['data'];
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($formData); die;
    $_SESSION['formData'] = $formData;
    echo 'Open File 3 to check submitted data.'
?>
```

file3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['formData']) && $_SESSION['formData'] != ''){
    print_r($_SESSION['formData']);
} else {
    echo 'Submit form first.';
}
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: That's good, but $_SESSION don't save values if i go back to file1.php. How to make it save values in case that i changes pages?

Comment: Remove session_destroy();  from file3.php and now your values will be saved untill you will submit your new data again using file1.php